# Add copy to email if boolean field in data extension is true

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I want to add some copy into an email only if the boolean (@CPD) in my data extension is TRUE.

Can someone provide me with an example of code to do this? Can I have the copy in the AMPscript of the email? Would this cope with html?

The logic is that that IF a course is certified (@CPD = TRUE), THEN include "**this copy here** 
 and this copy underneath"

... I'm not a developer and am self-teaching, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer can be found here: [AMPscript issue with a conditional (boolean)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316375/ampscript-issue-with-a-conditional-boolean), but you're thinking in the right direction.

```
%%[If @CPD Then]%%
```

Copy to display if boolean is true.

```
%%[Else]%%
```

Copy to display if boolean is false; can also be left blank if wanting to display nothing in these cases.

```
%%[EndIf]%%
```

*Making the assumption that you've figured out how to return the value of @CPD in the message. That is, that the lookup part of this process is already sorted out, if not - let me know, I can flesh out the code w/some additional details from you.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works beautifully!
I'd assumed that you'd need some kind of True/False logic, e.g. 

%%[IF @CPD == TRUE THEN]%%
Copy to display if boolean is true.
%%[ELSE]%%
Copy to display if boolean is false
%%[ENDIF]%%

Very interested to see that it works without. Really appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Comment: Annoyingly, I've found that this works in Preview & Test, but not when I have sent tests. The emails will send where the boolean value is False, but not if True.
Will report back if I find out a solution (just in case anyone is following this!)

Comment: Think the issue is with the copy (emails will send if I remove this) >> Possibly an issue with the copy breaking up the ampscript.

Comment: Hi @KatiePorteous - can you validate that the variable is producing a value? That is, remove the If/Else and instead have %%=v(@CPD)=%% in the email to make sure a value is coming through. Additionally, when you say it works in tests previews, but not the send - is the email failing, or is it delivering not respecting the code?